Los graficos en documentos pdf creados con rmarkdown salen recortados
Al crear un documento pdf en rmarkdown los gráficos salen recortados por los bordes y no se alcanza a ver completo

Todas las imagenes salen como la anterior en el documento.
Este es el yml del documento
---
title: "Análisis ..."
subtitle: |
  | Emul......
  | P.......
author: 
  - "Autor 1"
  - "Autor 2
lang: "es-CO"
date: "`r stringr::str_to_sentence( format(Sys.Date(), '%B-%Y') )`"
output: 
      pdf_document:
            toc: true
            toc_depth: 2
            df_print: kable
            highlight: tango
            fig_caption: yes
            keep_tex: yes
toc-title: "Contenido"
header-includes:
      - \usepackage{amsmath}
      - \usepackage{booktabs}
      - \usepackage{longtable}
      - \usepackage{array}
      - \usepackage{multirow}
      - \usepackage{wrapfig}
      - \usepackage{float}
      - \usepackage{colortbl}
      - \usepackage{pdflscape}
      - \usepackage{tabu}
      - \usepackage{threeparttable}
      - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
      - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
      - \usepackage{makecell}
      - \usepackage{xcolor, soul}
      - \usepackage{wasysym} # Icono telefono
      - \usepackage[misc]{ifsym} # icono mail
      - \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent, fancyhdr, lastpage}
      - \pagestyle{fancy}
      # Encabezado y pie de pagina
      - \rhead{Análisis de datos .....}
      - \lhead{P.....}
      - \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{Confidencial}}
      - \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}
      - \cfoot{\thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}
params:
  exp: "Numero Exp"
  precio_vta: 9999
  precio_lechon: 300000
  conf: 0.9
  dif_importante: 200
  intv_pcc: 10
  lim_gd: 16
  k: 10
  n: 4
  rg_pie: !r c(-Inf, 130, 140, Inf)
  seurop: !r c(-Inf, 0.4, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, Inf)
bibliography: ../Trabajo.bib
---

Así es la configuración del chunk setup
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, 
                      fig.align = "center")

library(conflicted)


El documento pdf se genera y aparentemente está bien pero las imagenes no se ven completas.
En la carpeta creada en la compilación del archivo .tex los imagenes quedan recortadas por lo que parece que el error es en la generación de las imagenes.

En RMarkdown es posible configurar el tamaño de una imagen en relación al espacio que debe ocupar en el documento pdf con los parámetros out.width y out.height.
Esta configuración se puede llamar desde el encabezado de cada pedazo de código (code chunk), por ejemplo, para que una imagen aparezca con un ancho equivalente al 50% del documento se llama así:
{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="50%", fig.cap="A nice image."}
knitr::include_graphics("foo/bar.png")

Para que el tamaño aparezca en función del tamaño del documento pdf, el argumento se pasa como un caracter y con el signo de porcentaje: "50%". También es posible pasar unidades específicas.
Fuente: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html
